# Podio .NET client failing to deserialize item: JSON integer is too large or small for an Int32

Tags: c#, .net, json, podio

Our Podio webhooks integration started breaking because of the following error:

Using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio.Async latest version.

`JSON integer 2149591369 is too large or small for an Int32. Path 'current_revision.item_revision_id', line 1, position 14100.`

Which happens in `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)`.

So as I understand the `item_revision_id` should be changed to `long` to not break?

Is there anything else I can do on my side, besides making a pull request to their [repo](https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet), that is not maintained and most likely won't be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR for this fix is already made, fix is on it's way, stay calm :)

You can also fix it yourself and build locally.

Comment: so the library IS maintained?

Comment: also, is there an ETA on when the fix will be released?

Comment: ETA - soon, feel free to fork, fix, compile locally and keep it all running until fresh nuget package is ready

Comment: I'm sure happy to hear that it's impossible to give a rough estimate on how long changing int to long might take. Is it days, months, weeks, years, decades? Can we at least establish a time range? If it's a couple of days it might be easier for us to update the nuget package when it comes out and then rerun the failed transactions than make our own build and deploy it to all services that need it, monitor when you release a new package and return to it.

Comment: I hope to have it all done tomorrow, but can't guarantee anything, and don't want you to blame anybody that release of this fix is delayed.

Comment: @LLL - new version of  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Podio.Async is just published. Can you please give it a try to confirm it works well?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio It looks like this has happened again now with the item_id which no longer fits within Int32. I forked/modified/built my own local copy, and I'd be happy to submit a PR if you're willing?

Comment: @liquidki - please submit a PR, no promises on when it will be merged and released :)

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio Awesome! I will do that. Understood on the no promises, I thought this was a shot in the dark to begin with! For some reason after I built the code myself, all my methods became Async whereas before I was using the Sync version. I searched but I couldn't figure out how to build both versions out of the single codebase. Do you have any links to how this is set up?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio I submitted the PR (https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/pull/59).

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio Is there an ETA on a merge of the pull request + new package released?